How can I insert a categorical moderating variable into a looped t-test?
I am coding a series of analyses from a dataset "receive". It has 70 survey results and 60 dependent variables. Some of the independent (demographic) variables are categorical, some are binary. The binary ones I am running t-tests on, looping through all the dependent variables to uncover relationships. However, some differences between the demographics (for example whether the participants were members of community organisations "CommOrg") between the different municipalities (n = 3) the research was conducted in makes me iffy about the significance of some results in the t-tests. So I want to run the t-tests with the categorical variable municipality "Municipality" as a moderating variable.
The current (functional, but not including a moderating variable) code is as follows:
lapply(receive[8:68], function(x) t.test(x~receive$CommOrg))
I tried to resolve this by adding an interaction effect in the same way it is coded in my ANOVA analyses:
lapply(receive[8:68], function(x) t.test(x~receive$CommOrg*receive$Municipality))
I tried some other very similar ways, but to no avail. Could you help out?
